# Django - Pagination display

Tags: django, pagination

I am having an issue figuring out my pagination for django. Following the docs everything works correctly if I am on the first page or the last page, but I have code duplicating. Everything I have tried I end up getting some sort of exception, mostly empty page exception. I understand that this is because my solutions involve not checking if page_obj.has_previous or .has_next. I am not sure how to solve this and any help would be greatly appreciated. I will attach a screen shot so you can see what I mean.

pagination:

```
<div class="pagination justify-content-center pt-3">
      <nav aria-label='pagination'>
          <ul class="pagination step-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label='Previous'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class='page-link'>
                    {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class='page-link'>
                    {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label='Next'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'> &raquo; </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

[image: example]

As you can see the '2 of 3' gets duplicated. I see exactly why it gets duplicated in my code but if I delete one of the list items then the `{{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}`  will not be displayed on the first or last page. What would be the best way to solve this? I haven't been able to figure it out on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code (page-item class) just has to be outside the if block. This will work.

```
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label='Previous'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                
            {% endif %}
               <li class="page-item">
                    <a class='page-link'>
                    {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}
                    </a>
                </li>

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label='Next'>
                        <span aria-hidden='true'> &raquo; </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endif %}
```